# Linking of two tables LinqToSql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have two tables that I want to link together. Table 1 will be projects: Id, Name, Date. Table 2 will be contents: Id, Name, Text. I want to link many contents to one project and then ask for the names of contents that are linked to a given project.

Example:

I have a content with: `Id=1, Name=Content1, Text=blablabla.`

And another content with: `Id=2, Name=Content2, Text=HelloHello`

And a project: `Id=1, Name=Project, Date=27.01.2019, ContentsId=1, 2.`

First question: How can I link them together?
Second question: How can I ask for the content's names in a project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your database is correctly set up any Foreign Key relationship will follow into the LinqToSql objects so I'd suggest you check that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For local collections that would work perfectly: (I've added dummy classes for type checking)

```
void Main()
{
    var t1 = new T1[] { new T1(), new T1() };
    var t2 = new T2[] { new T2(), new T2() };

    var joinQuery = 
        from r1 in t1
        from r2 in t2
        where r2.ContentsId.Contains(r1.Id) == true
        select new { name1 = r1.Name, text = r1.Text, name2 = r2.Name };
}

class T1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string Text { get;set; }
}

class T2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int[] ContentsId { get; set; }
}
```

**joinQuery** it's the key thing, so it returns collection of anonymous objects, where name1 - name from 1st collection, text - text from 1st collection, name2 - name from 2nd collection

Hope that helps.

Comment: If I get this right T1 and T2 are for Content and Project right? and this would be equal for a normal sql Table, right?

Comment: Yes, it's Content and Project, that should work for sql tables, you can check produced SQL query if you want, it should be pretty straightforward.